# Mysql every derived table must have its own aliases error

Tags: mysql

I want to select distinct records from table sabha_cluster. I have used following query but "Mysql every derived table must have its own aliases error" occured.

```
mysql> select mps.scode,mps.tlit,mps.amnt,mps.pr from milk_payment_summary mps
join society_master s on mps.scode=s.scode inner join (select distinct c.scode
rom sabha_cluster c) where mps.date1 between '2014-01-16' and '2014-02-15' && c.scode=44;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an alias to the derived table, like this:

```
select mps.scode,mps.tlit, mps.amnt,mps.pr 
from milk_payment_summary mps
join society_master s 
on mps.scode=s.scode 
join (
  select distinct c.scode from sabha_cluster c
) AS t
on t.scode = s.scode
where mps.date1 between '2014-01-16' and '2014-02-15' and t.scode=44
```

Here `t` is the alias of derived table.

Comment: select mps.scode,mps.tlit, mps.amnt,mps.pr 
from milk_payment_summary mps
join society_master s 
on mps.scode=s.scode 
join (
  select distinct c.scode from sabha_cluster c
) AS t
on t.scode = s.scode
where mps.date1 between '2014-01-16' and '2014-02-15' and t.scode=44

Answer (score 2):

You need an alias for your subquery:

```
mysql> select mps.scode,mps.tlit,mps.amnt,mps.pr from milk_payment_summary mps
join society_master s on mps.scode=s.scode inner join (select distinct c.scode
from sabha_cluster c) x where mps.date1 between '2014-01-16' and '2014-02-15' && x.scode=44;
```

Note that you have to use that same alias, not `c`, in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    mps.scode, mps.tlit, mps.amnt, mps.pr
from
    milk_payment_summary mps
        join
    society_master s ON mps.scode = s.scode
        inner join
    (select distinct
        c.scode
    from
        sabha_cluster c) d
where
    mps.date1 between '2014-01-16' and '2014-02-15'
        AND d.scode = 44;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this code ..........

```
 select mps.scode,mps.tlit,mps.amnt,mps.pr from milk_payment_summary mps
    join society_master s on mps.scode=s.scode inner join (select distinct scode
    from sabha_cluster) as c where mps.scode=c.scode and ( mps.date1 between '2014-01-16' and '2014-02-15') and c.scode=44;
```